# Drupal 7 Views : Filter Event : only show events when start date <= start date + 3 weeks

Tags: views

I have a list of Upcoming Events that shows all events in chronological order starting with Today. Most events last only a week or two at most, but we also have exhibitions that run for 3-4 months. They end up at the top of the list the whole time, with more immediate events below them, so I want all events to appear only for the first three weeks after the Start Date.

The Filter Criteria in Views allows you to state a date relative to Now, TODAY, Monday, or a specific date, but I cannot figure out how to make a filter that is relative to the Start Date itself.

Comment: I figured it out:  
Display if Start Date >= Today - 21 days && if End Date >= Today